# How to organize top level scripts in Python projects, especially for interactively developing

Tags: python, code-organization

I have a Python project that looks something like this.

```
project/
    tests/
        __init__.py
        tests.py
    main_module/
        __init__.py
        sub_modules/
        ...
    task1.py
    task2.py
    ...
    outputs/
    data/
```

For context, `main_module` implements a whole bunch of numerical computing code and simulations and the files `task1.py`, `task2.py` are scripts that glue together things from `main_module` and `data` then store output (figures, tables, etc.) in `outputs`.  These are distinct from things in `tests` and could maybe be described as user code.

Each task file can take quite a long time to run, so it is quite convenient to develop them interactively and plot intermediate results and so on to check what is going on -- this cannot realistically be simply placed into `tests/`.

If I put each `task` file into a subdirectory `main_tasks/` or something, then I can't import from `main_module` unless I make `project/` itself a module.  However, this seems to make interactivity very difficult since you get `ImportErrors` on any relative imports.  **So, what is the right way to organize these top level `task` scripts into a subfolder so that they aren't polluting `project/`?**  Is it proper to just do something like:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/main_module/")
```

?  In a `tasks` subfolder?  Should I install main_module in `site-packages`?  Should I develop interactively in the top level, then move the tasks into a bona fide module after they're working?

For context I've looked at https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/ and some other project organization questions on SO but didn't feel my issue was adequately addressed.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a similar structure in some of my projects and I prefer to keep these top level scripts in a subfolder so that the project root doesn't get cluttered.
This works fairly easy without modifying the sys.path by using an editable installation of the package.
In a shell in the root folder of the package do:

```
pip install -e .
```

This will install the package in your local python library in a way that always reflects changes you make in your package code. Then you just import that package as you would any other package in your scripts and it doesn't matter where the scripts are located.
See [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)

I guess it is necessary to have a setup.py script for this to work, but the convenience of the editable install is worth it.